# AWS Stepfunctions using SageMaker ScriptProcessor

Tags: python, aws, sagemaker, mlops

Hello Data Science/Engineer folks,

I need a help in orchestrating a ML model using AWS Step Functions. There are some tutorials on using StepFunction with Python SDKs, but all of them are focused around using built in SageMaker container. For my project, I have a custom containers for pre-processing and training the model.

I am having trouble on executing PreProcessing with StepFunctions.
Below is my ScriptProcessor code:

```
from sagemaker.processing import ScriptProcessor, ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput

script_processor = ScriptProcessor(
    command=['python3'],
    image_uri=preprocessing_image,
    role=role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
)

script_processor.run(
    code="preprocessing_container/preprocessing/preprocessing.py",
    inputs=[ProcessingInput(source=input_data_path, destination="/opt/ml/processing/input")],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train_data",
                         source="/opt/ml/processing/output/train",
                         destination="{}/{}".format(output_data_path, "train_data")),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test_data",
                         source="/opt/ml/processing/output/test",
                         destination="{}/{}".format(output_data_path, "test_data")),
    ],
    arguments=["--train-test-split-ratio", "0.2"]
)
```

Step Function:

```
# Create Processing Step
processing_step = ProcessingStep(
    "SageMaker pre-processing step",
    processor=script_processor,
    job_name=execution_input["PreprocessJobName"],    
    inputs=inputs,
    outputs=outputs,
    container_arguments=["--train-test-split-ratio", "0.2"],
    container_entrypoint=["python3", "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/preprocessing.py"],
)
```

This last block of code doesn't seem to accept **ScriptProcessor** method of SageMaker. Upon executing the StepFunction Workflow as below:

```
workflow_definition = Chain([
    processing_step
])

# Next, we define the workflow
workflow = Workflow(
    name="MyWorkflow-preprocess",
    definition=workflow_definition,
    role=workflow_execution_role
)

workflow.create()
```

I get following errors:

**ClientError**: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateStateMachine operation: 'arn:aws:iam::292065629009:role/AmazonSageMaker-StepFunctionsWorkflowExecutionRole' is not authorized to create managed-rule.

I initially thought it was permission issue, however, i was able to execute a simple stepfunction workflow using 'hello world' example.

I am wondering, if anyone has a way to come around this step.
Thank you

Comment: please post the full error message

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the error message. I updated the original message with addition steps as well.